# Trouble with brackets yet again

Tags: javascript

I have been working on loops and conditionals lately. I have been pretty successful in understanding the concepts, but the brackets continue to confuse me. Without the bracket at the end of line three, and the very last bracket at the bottom, the call log will not read "Generator #1 is off." like it should. Why do those brackets make such a big difference?

```
var totalGen = 19;
var totalMW = 0;
for (var genNumber = 1; genNumber <= totalGen; genNumber++){
  if (genNumber <= 4 && genNumber % 2 == 0) {
    totalMW += 62;
   console.log("Generator #" + genNumber + " is on, adding 62 MW, for a total                 of " + totalMW + " MW!");
  }
  else if (genNumber >= 5 && genNumber % 2 == 0) {
    totalMW += 124;
    console.log("Generator #" + genNumber + " is on, adding 124 MW, for a     total of " + totalMW + " MW!");
  }
    else {
      console.log("Generator #" + genNumber + " is off.");
    }
}
```

Comment: The output is identical either way. Compare [with the brackets](http://jsfiddle.net/qvt0j8jg/) and [without them](http://jsfiddle.net/qvt0j8jg/1/).

Comment: I don't see brackets on line 3. Line 3 seems to me to be totalMW += 62;

Comment: @BenjyKessler: That's because line 2 wasn't in the code block, so line 3 looked like line 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, those brackets doesn't make any difference at all.

When there is only one statement in the loop (as it is here), the brackets are not needed.

```
for (a, b, c) d;
```

does exactly the same as:

```
for (a, b, c) { d; }
```

---

Personally I always use brackets, even if there is only one statement in the block. I think that it makes the code easier to read and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at it as statements or groups of statements. If you only have a single statement then there is no need for the curly brackets.

For example:

```
for(...) statement;
if (cond1) statement;
else if (cond2) statement;
```

A statement can be a single line. If you however need multiple statements, you need to use curly brackets to group them:

```
for(...) {
    statement 1;
    statement 2;
    etc..
}

if (cond1) statement;  // single line
else if (cond2) {      // group, only executed if cond2 is true
    statement 1;
    statement 2;
}
else                  // single line
    statement;
```

This way the browser will know that all these statements belong to a single step.

If you however did this:

```
if (cond)
    statement 1;
    statement 2;
```

only statement 1 will be executed if cond is true. statement 2 will be executed regardless, in other words, it will be the same as:

```
if (cond) statement 1;

statement 2;
```

Using brackets in all cases can be a good habit as it prevents accidents where several statements are added to a condition etc.

Answer (score 0):

For loops and if statements are contained within curly braces - that's the syntax.

So if you embed an if inside a for, each block must be inside its respective block.

```
if(something){
    return;
 }

for(i=0; i<10; i++){// open curly for the for
      if(i == 4){//curly for the if
          console.log('i is 4!');
      }//end curly for the if
 }//end curly for the for
```

Comment: That's not correct. The braces is not part of the syntax for the `if` or the `for` statement, they are used to group statements. See the syntax for the `for` statement: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for_statement Not a single one of the braces in your example is required.

Comment: First, evidentially the line numbers got messed up in the OP's post so perhaps my answer wasn't relevant, and second, his post has braces - his question was not whether or not he could/should use them. Also, have fun minifying without them.

Comment: His question was why there was a different result with and without the braces (which it isn't). Your answer says that the braces are always required, which they aren't.

Comment: I never once said they're always required.

Comment: That's what the first sentence in the answer says, even if you didn't intend it.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop in javascript works with or without curly-braces.

```
for (...) {
    //statement
}
```

is the same as

```
for (...)
    //statement
```

However, this is only true for single statements...

```
for (...) {
    if (...) {
        //A
    }

    if (....) {
        //B
    }
}
```

is *not* the same as

```
for (...)
    if (...) {
        //A
    }

    if (....) {
        //B
    }
```

as only the first `if` will be caught by the for loop, the other if will be ignored until the loop has finished.

In your code you have a singular `if-then-else-if-then-else` statement and so it is caught by the for loop.